# Axios interceptor expiration time

Tags: javascript, api, rest, axios, endpoint

Below I will post my AXIOS code. What happens first when I start the application (Vue js) is that it opens login page and when I enter username/password I set token and refresh token in local storage. That works fine and I can make other api calls which require token. The problem happens when it expires (in 3 minutes after login), it goes into infinite loop. Also the thing is I don't know how to check expiration time of refresh token because I can't decode it with this function I wrote.

Access token:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiMTg4YjQ0NDg2MzdmMmJhYWRkMDE1MmU5OWRhNGIwMWYxMzgxMzVjY2Q5YjA2NmRlM2M4YjFkZjk4ODE1ZGZmNGZhOGE2ODQ2YWI4ZjY1YjkiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjE1MzcxOTAuNjg5MjgzLCJuYmYiOjE2MjE1MzcxOTAuNjg5Mjg2LCJleHAiOjE2MjE1MzczNzAuNjc3NDM3LCJzdWIiOiIyIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.U5lNHetMq6vEnUKwxlJ9sa9lU6ahj-lDlxjWFdaTuXaGCcmx8zb917OSKkZa1g8PA3NArC6nMVbWfbD44DXLF3I6UFFXAYNncuH8kAngIh-XyRhUgr3MDOR04dCb02Khchs30QnbznHFvox1wtTXLEIT2wzdGI0_GGQot3ZFvxBfukRVt64uqC7GrVxcpoZXV2LXY7LxkZXoEd88QFcjfWWw_RC1fyU7gNaGxF4xml5CyJGZOcM1S-1QlBsXE-HE5qeJPZilxOJLHvxSYo-HFTbl7u0WNlryyCAxJqoeMHIqmHrEmZX261IdMFdQ7sl9YP-rXtg5hY_SDVoaE-KjHThltKvPkV_XeWxWQ3KqCDqm7UMZyxkWzEMglE4Ym8hvNsgUIlZMVeKCuYkQ2Vri-X2whttaVwM4-pJPbAqJURYu2WRDWgBbIWWkXkw4GLUFTDIllOmIBESUjba_L3x2dHrce3PpBOBw8dYDPttdqch6t_J7vBsRUu8-DcHDzxnVu6vBYmQA-TAlI9yN7gOgn_gMDMq6FhitKuQ9KghACJmTjqB-_BbxAI3pWwAuPeAas7uB9ugzpScKPPZtThoI08wQ8pT7Xz8JvZTEharzUHcldu2rIlUCif6l-rtszIQNYcCfWFMBVP9HFRSgCcEtgl3L5SPfQGW0Ytc2P_ED4HE

Refresh token:

> 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

They are different, when I decode access token I get an object which has this key **"exp":1621533539.9695** which is expiration time, but not for refresh token.

Any idea?

```js
export const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: "*/*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
});


// CHECK IF TOKEN IS EXPIRED (DECODE TOKEN)
function isTokenExpired(token) {
  const base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
  const base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
  const jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
    atob(base64)
      .split("")
      .map(function (c) {
        return "%" + ("00" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      })
      .join("")
  );
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
  const expirationDate = data.exp;
  const currentDate = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  return currentDate >= expirationDate;
}


API.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    let refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");

    //if refresh token is expired we logout and return early
    // if (refreshToken) {
    //   const isExpired = isTokenExpired(refreshToken);
    //   if (isExpired) {
    //     localStorage.setItem("accessToken", "");
    //     localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", "");
    //     router.push({ path: "/login" });
    //   }
    //   return config;
    // }

    // if token is expired we refresh the token
    if (token) {
      const isExpired = isTokenExpired(token);
      if (isExpired) {
        const data = await API.post("/token", {
          grant_type: "refresh_token",
          refresh_token: refreshToken,
        });
        if (data) {
          token = data.access_token;
          localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.data.access_token);
          localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", data.data.refresh_token);
        }
      }
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);



//CHECK AFTER REQUEST IF RESPONSE IS 401
API.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    let refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");

    if (error.response?.status && error.response?.status === 401) {
      const data = await API.post("/token", {
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
      });
      if (data) {
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.data.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", data.data.refresh_token);
        error.config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + data.access_token;
        return API.request(error.config);
      }
    }
    throw error.response;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The refresh token does't come with and expiration date.
You need to try getting a new token with it. If it is invalid, your API will tell you, then you need to send your user back to login page.

I think you know the refresh token flow, but I'll leave it here anyway:

1. Check if you have a token and a Refresh Token in your localStorage.
2. Once you have them, check if the token is expired.
3. if it is expired, you need to send the refresh token to your api.
4. The API will give you another token and refreshToken, store them and continue making requests.
5. If the API reject the refreshToken, send your user to login page.

I have a complete example of refreshToken and reattempt request if you need.

Everytime your token expires you need to do the refresh token process.

Comment: Can you please send me an example? I am still struggling with this :/